# Android service stops collecting data when the screen is turned off

Tags: android, service, sensors

So I have a service that logs ProximitySensor data.

It all works fine when I have the screen ON, but like 5 seconds after the screen goes OFF the log stops.

How can I keep my Android service running when the screen is turned off?

Comment: why this question is downvoted? I think some people tend to downvote a question if they can't answer it. My question about showing badge in Android had 9 downvotes, but look now every vendor is supporting badges in Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a [partial wake lock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html), but it will eat the battery like candy.

Comment: @Geralt do you know any efficient way?

Comment: @cesarferreira If you intend for your app to run all the time, even when the device is otherwise inactive, you have to obtain a partial wake lock. Or use the AlarmManager, which obtains its own wake lock. I was just warning you that it will have an impact on battery life. There isn't any other way.